# Perl/cpan: Can't locate JSON/Parse.pm @INC

Tags: linux, perl, centos, centos7

I'm running on CentOS 7.

I've installed JSON::Parse via cpan but getting the error.

```
Can't locate JSON/Parse.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
/home/truckassist/modules 
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 
/usr/local/share/perl5 
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/lib64/perl5 
/usr/share/perl5 .)
```

When running `cpan JSON::Parse` I get the following: `JSON::Parse is up to date (0.62)`

I've tried the following so far...

```
perl -e "print qq(@INC)"
```

Output:

```
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3 
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/root/perl5/lib/perl5 
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 
/usr/local/share/perl5 
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/lib64/perl5 
/usr/share/perl5
```

Also:

`find /root/perl5 -iname '*json*'`

Output:

```
/root/perl5/bin/cpanel_json_xs
/root/perl5/bin/json_pp
/root/perl5/bin/validjson
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/JSON
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cpanel/JSON
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Cpanel/JSON
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/JSON
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/JSON
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/JSON.pm
/root/perl5/man/man1/cpanel_json_xs.1
/root/perl5/man/man1/json_pp.1
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::PP.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::PP::Boolean.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::backportPP.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::backportPP::Boolean.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::backportPP::Compat5005.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::backportPP::Compat5006.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::Parse.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/Cpanel::JSON::XS.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/Cpanel::JSON::XS::Boolean.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/Cpanel::JSON::XS::Type.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::MaybeXS.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::Tokenize.3pm
/root/perl5/man/man3/JSON::Whitespace.3pm
```

I can only assume it's looking at the incorrect cpan/perl directory.

Can anyone please assist or provide some direction?

Comment: Run `cpan` and type `info JSON::Parse` into the CPAN shell. It should tell you where the module is installed on your machine.

Comment: @choroba It is installed here ```/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/JSON/Parse.pod```

Comment: How is the failing script being run? It appears from the `@INC` dumps that the Perl running the failing script is not the one you get when you type `perl` at the shell prompt.

Comment: `.pod` is just documentation. You did not show where it's installed. Please provide the output of the following: `head -n 1 "$( which cpan )"` and `echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep -P 'make|mbuild'` and `set | grep ^PERL`. And if you can, the location of `JSON/Parse.pm`

Comment: Is the error message `Can't locate JSON/parse.pm` or `Can't locate JSON/Parse.pm`? Your question isn't consistent.

Comment: @ikegami Output in order of your requests: 1. ```#!/usr/bin/perl```, 2. ```the new mechanism. Please read more about it and make your choice```, 3. ```PERL5LIB=/root/perl5/lib/perl5
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=:/root/perl5:/root/perl5:/root/perl5:/root/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT='--install_base /root/perl5'
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/root/perl5```

Comment: Here is the install DIR: ```/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/JSON/Parse.pm```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You installed the module in a non-standard directory (`/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi`),<sup>[1]</sup> and you didn't tell `perl` about it<sup>[2]</sup>, or you don't have sufficient permissions to access it.

Make sure other users have the permissions needed to access `/root/perl5` and its contents.

And to let `perl` know where the find the modules, you could use

```bash
export PERL5LIB=/root/perl5/lib/perl5
```

---

Alternatively, stop installing the module in an unusual location when installing for everyone on the machine.

Unset `PERL_MB_OPT` and `PERL_MM_OPT` (and `PERL5LIB`) when root,<sup>[3]</sup> then re-install the module. You might want to get rid of `/root/perl5` to avoid confusion.

---

1. You are using local::lib as root, installing modules "just for root".
2. Except when running as root, which is why `cpan` finds it when root.
3. For example, by not using local::lib as root.

Comment: Thanks, the first option didn't do the trick, but unsetting the global variables helped and did the trick.

Comment: Adjusted the export. Perl should automatically add the last bit. But that's not why it didn't work. You probably set it in the wrong process to affect your script. Or you had a permission problem accessing the directory. Added a note about permissions to answer.